# How should I represent my network?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I am sort of having a problem on how I should represent network for training my CNN. The input data consists of different sized images, in which the number of rows is constant (441 rows) and the dimension of the color is constant (RGB), but the number of columns is different. The CNN are supposed to generate a feature vector, in which the length of feature is dependent of the number of columns each image has.

Example:

An image shaped (441,300,3)  should generate a feature vector of length 98

An image shaped (441,1209,3) should generate a feature vector of length 398

So nearly each column should generate 3 features.

Is it possible to make convolution using kernel that fill the whole column and give out 3 features? The reason why I am seeking for a kernel that fill the whole column, as I want to apply more importance on some areas of the columns, instead of giving all the area equal importance.

If so, how would go by designing such kernel or such a network in keras?

Comment: Can you explain how are you computing the feature vector lengths from the image shapes?

Comment: The length of the feature vector is given beforehand.

Comment: Are you interested in transfer learning or you want to train your `CNN` from scratch?

Comment: I am not sure i understand the question?